# Android MediaPlayer turns black when it is paused and orientation changes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-orientation

I'm using SurfaceView with MediaPlayer. When the video is playing everything works as expected, it changes its size acoording to the new orientation and keeps playing. The problem is when paused. When the video is in pause state, it is visible, but then, when I changes orientation it turns black, every thing else stays the same like my seekbar and a text view.
 this is how I handle orientation changes:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { 
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setVideoSize(mediaPlayer);
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(videoWidth,videoHeight));  

        ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) surfaceView.getLayoutParams()).gravity =     Gravity.CENTER;
    }
```

setVideoSize() sets videoWidth and videoHeight according to the screen resolution.
How come that when playing it works and when paused, it doesn't?

Comment: When playing SurfaceView updated with new frame during playback. Assume SurfaceView lost content or destroyed/recreated on orientation change.